# How we can show Highchart column-placement chart for negative values?

Tags: highcharts

We have to create a chart and tried but it is not showing the column in case of negative value in the data.
for link :
'https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-placement'
I have put a negative value and it is not showing a column for it, how we can achieve it for column-placement chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `min` restriction for y-axis.

```
    yAxis: [{
        // min: 0,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xq8ejgnf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min